# mysql relationships in EER

Tags: mysql, sql

I made an EER diagram in MySQL. The end goal is to be able to have a few tables (fleet1, fleet2, fleet3) that are comprised of a unique certificate id, but have multiple vendors and multiple vessels. In each fleet, the vendor can appear more than once, but each vessel only once. When everything is complete, I will connect this database to mail merge and be able to query data from each fleet.

I want to see all of the columns from the vendor table, as well as all of the columns from the vessel table inside of each fleet table

Would a linking table suffice to link the tables?

I tried a one-to-many (creating a linking table which would be each fleet table), but I want each fleet table to comprise of all of the vendor information and all of the fleet information, so that when I do a mail merge I see certificate id, all vendor info, and all vessel info.

I am in 2NF, but can I simplify further into 3NF?

[image: EER diagram]

Comment: What's the relationship between `vessel`, `fleetx`, and `vendor`?  Why do you have multiple `fleetx` table?

Comment: @Eric 
each fleet is essentially an insurance group.
So in each fleet, insurance vendor A could appear multiple times, but only have one unique vessel and certificate ID. For example purposes, let's just say there is only 1 vendor and only 1 vessel here. If I wanted to link these 2 tables together on fleet1 and fleet2, wouldn't that mean that each fleetx is the linking table? So if i query data from fleetx, i would use two joins, to join vendor to fleetx and vessel to fleetx?

Comment: In this case, `fleetx` table can have a `vesselId` since the relationship is many-to-one.  From my understanding, your relationship between `fleetx` and `vendor` is many-to-many.  So you will need intermediary table (eg: fleetvendor) to turn it into one-to-many.